# Drop duplicates with a subset of 2 columns but another column must be different?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        "po": [1, 2, 1, 1]
      , "msn": [111, 222, 111, 111]
      , "delivery_time": ["2021-09-01", "2021-09-01", "2021-09-05", "2021-09-08", ]
      , "amount": [10, 20, 30, 40]
      , "source": ["A", "B", "C", "C"]})
```

|  | PO | PRODUCT_NUMBER | DELIVERY_TIME | AMOUNT | SOURCE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 111 | 2021-09-01 | 10 | A |
| 1 | 2 | 222 | 2021-09-01 | 20 | B |
| 2 | 1 | 111 | 2021-09-05 | 30 | C |
| 3 | 1 | 111 | 2021-09-08 | 40 | C |

I want to drop duplicates with (subset=["PO", "PRODUCT_NUMBER"], keep="last") but "SOURCE" must be different.

So

- row 0 has same "PO" + "PRODUCT_NUMBER" as row 2 but a different "SOURCE" --> drop row 0
- row 2 has same "PO" + "PRODUCT_NUMBER" as row 3 but same "SOURCE" --> keep row 2 and 3

The end result should be:

|  | PO | PRODUCT_NUMBER | DELIVERY_TIME | AMOUNT | SOURCE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 222 | 2021-09-01 | 20 | B |
| 2 | 1 | 111 | 2021-09-05 | 30 | C |
| 3 | 1 | 111 | 2021-09-08 | 40 | C |

How can I do that with pandas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try two `duplicated`

```
out = df[df.duplicated(['po','msn','source'],keep=False) | ~df.duplicated(['po','msn'],keep=False)]
Out[354]: 
   po  msn delivery_time  amount source
1   2  222    2021-09-01      20      B
2   1  111    2021-09-05      30      C
3   1  111    2021-09-08      40      C
```

Comment: Thanks, could you please explain that code a bit? It works but I'm not sure how it works.